# trying leaflet tutorial I get a broken map

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps, leaflet

I have followed leaflet "[get started](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html)" tutorial

but my map looks broken and the polygons are not on the map like in the example:

example:
[image]

my map html:

[image]

my html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="elad_map.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="elad_map.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
document.onload = loadMap();

function loadMap() {
  var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);


  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'your.mapbox.project.id',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.public.access.token'
  }).addTo(map);


  var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  }).addTo(map);

  var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
  ]).addTo(map);

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things that would cause this and they are all related to CSS. Please make sure Leaflet's CSS is loaded by checking the networktab in your developer tools:

[image]

If it's loaded correctly than you have other CSS rules in place (elad_map.css) which interfere with Leaflet's CSS rules.